# Trying to load a yaml file, iterate through the hash and execute some logic

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem, pageobjects

Trying to load a yaml file, iterate through the hash and execute some logic. I'm using Watir-Webdriver/Ruby to answer randomly selected questions, the questions/answers are known and stored in a YAML file (kba.yml).

I'm using Ruby/Page Objects/YAML file/Watir-Webdriver.

My YAML file (kba.yml):

```
1:
  question: "Which of the following is a current or previous employer? If there is not a matched employer name, please select 'NONE OF THE ABOVE'."
  answer: "Google"

2:  
  question: "According to our records, you graduated from which of the following High Schools?"
  answer: "NONE OF THE ABOVE/DOES NOT APPLY"

3:  
  question: "I was born within a year or on the year of the date below."
  answer_1: "1942"
  answer_2: "1941"
  answer_3: "1943"
```

Where I load my YAML file (inside my env.rb):

```
require 'yaml'
KBA = YAML.load_file('config/data/kba.yml')
```

My code to iterate over hash from yaml file and perform some logic:

## Loop for first random question:

```
KBA.each do |key, value| 
  value.each do |question, answer|
    puts "blah question: #{question}"
      if (@browser.h2s[0].text.sub (/^\d.\s/), '') == question
        puts "Question matched and selected: #{question}"
        case answer
        when @browser.labels[0].text
          select_first_q_first_radio
          puts "Answer matched and selected #{answer}"
        when @browser.labels[1].text
          select_first_q_second_radio
          puts "Answer matched and selected #{answer}"
        when @browser.labels[2].text
          select_first_q_third_radio
          puts "Answer matched and selected #{answer}"
        when @browser.labels[3].text
          select_first_q_fourth_radio
          puts "Answer matched and selected #{answer}"
        when @browser.labels[4].text
          select_first_q_fifth_radio 
          puts "Answer matched and selected #{answer}"
        else 
          puts "The answer is not present for this question!"
        end
      else
        puts "This question is not stored in the dataset: #{@browser.h2s[0].text}"
      end
    end
end
```

## Loop for second random question:

```
KBA.each do |question, answer| 
    if (@browser.h2s[1].text.sub (/^\d.\s/), '') == question
      puts "Question matched and selected: #{question}"
      case answer
      when @browser.labels[0].text
        select_second_q_first_radio
        puts "Answer matched and selected #{answer}"
      when @browser.labels[1].text
        select_second_q_second_radio
        puts "Answer matched and selected #{answer}"
      when @browser.labels[2].text
        select_second_q_third_radio
        puts "Answer matched and selected #{answer}"
      when @browser.labels[3].text
        select_second_q_fourth_radio
        puts "Answer matched and selected #{answer}"
      when @browser.labels[4].text
        select_second_q_fifth_radio 
        puts "Answer matched and selected #{answer}"
      else 
        puts "The answer is not present for this question!"
      end
    else
      puts "This question is not stored in the dataset: #{@browser.h2s[1].text}"
    end  
  end
```

## Loop for third random question:

```
  KBA.each do |question, answer| 
      if (@browser.h2s[2].text.sub (/^\d.\s/), '') == question
        puts "Question matched and selected: #{question}"
        case answer
        when @browser.labels[0].text
          select_third_q_first_radio
          puts "Answer matched and selected #{answer}"
        when @browser.labels[1].text
          select_third_q_second_radio
          puts "Answer matched and selected #{answer}"
        when @browser.labels[2].text
          select_third_q_third_radio
          puts "Answer matched and selected #{answer}"
        when @browser.labels[3].text
          select_third_q_fourth_radio
          puts "Answer matched and selected #{answer}"
        when @browser.labels[4].text
          select_third_q_fifth_radio 
          puts "Answer matched and selected #{answer}"
        else 
          puts "The answer is not present for this question!"
        end
      else
        puts "This question is not stored in the dataset: #{@browser.h2s[2].text}"
      end 
    end
end
```

From the output it seem's like my code isn't actually checking against the proper value of the question and answer, how would I do that?

This is the output:

```
blah question: question
This question is not stored in the dataset: 1. Which of the following is a current or previous employer? If there is not a matched employer name, please select 'NONE OF THE ABOVE'.
blah question: answer
This question is not stored in the dataset: 1. Which of the following is a current or previous employer? If there is not a matched employer name, please select 'NONE OF THE ABOVE'.
blah question: question
This question is not stored in the dataset: 1. Which of the following is a current or previous employer? If there is not a matched employer name, please select 'NONE OF THE ABOVE'.
blah question: answer
This question is not stored in the dataset: 1. Which of the following is a current or previous employer? If there is not a matched employer name, please select 'NONE OF THE ABOVE'.
blah question: question
This question is not stored in the dataset: 1. Which of the following is a current or previous employer? If there is not a matched employer name, please select 'NONE OF THE ABOVE'.
blah question: answer
This question is not stored in the dataset: 1. Which of the following is a current or previous employer? If there is not a matched employer name, please select 'NONE OF THE ABOVE'.
blah question: question
This question is not stored in the dataset: 1. Which of the following is a current or previous employer? If there is not a matched employer name, please select 'NONE OF THE ABOVE'.
blah question: answer
This question is not stored in the dataset: 1. Which of the following is a current or previous employer? If there is not a matched employer name, please select 'NONE OF THE ABOVE'.
blah question: question
This question is not stored in the dataset: 1. Which of the following is a current or previous employer? If there is not a matched employer name, please select 'NONE OF THE ABOVE'.
blah question: answer
This question is not stored in the dataset: 1. Which of the following is a current or previous employer? If there is not a matched employer name, please select 'NONE OF THE ABOVE'.
blah question: question
This question is not stored in the dataset: 1. Which of the following is a current or previous employer? If there is not a matched employer name, please select 'NONE OF THE ABOVE'.
blah question: answer
This question is not stored in the dataset: 1. Which of the following is a current or previous employer? If there is not a matched employer name, please select 'NONE OF THE ABOVE'.
blah question: question
This question is not stored in the dataset: 1. Which of the following is a current or previous employer? If there is not a matched employer name, please select 'NONE OF THE ABOVE'.
blah question: answer
This question is not stored in the dataset: 1. Which of the following is a current or previous employer? If there is not a matched employer name, please select 'NONE OF THE ABOVE'.
blah question: question
This question is not stored in the dataset: 1. Which of the following is a current or previous employer? If there is not a matched employer name, please select 'NONE OF THE ABOVE'.
blah question: answer_1
This question is not stored in the dataset: 1. Which of the following is a current or previous employer? If there is not a matched employer name, please select 'NONE OF THE ABOVE'.
blah question: answer_2
This question is not stored in the dataset: 1. Which of the following is a current or previous employer? If there is not a matched employer name, please select 'NONE OF THE ABOVE'.
blah question: answer_3
This question is not stored in the dataset: 1. Which of the following is a current or previous employer? If there is not a matched employer name, please select 'NONE OF THE ABOVE'.
This question is not stored in the dataset: 2. I was born within a year or on the year of the date below.
This question is not stored in the dataset: 2. I was born within a year or on the year of the date below.
This question is not stored in the dataset: 2. I was born within a year or on the year of the date below.
This question is not stored in the dataset: 2. I was born within a year or on the year of the date below.
This question is not stored in the dataset: 2. I was born within a year or on the year of the date below.
This question is not stored in the dataset: 2. I was born within a year or on the year of the date below.
This question is not stored in the dataset: 2. I was born within a year or on the year of the date below.
This question is not stored in the dataset: 2. I was born within a year or on the year of the date below.
This question is not stored in the dataset: 3. Which of the following represents the last four digits of your primary checking account number?
This question is not stored in the dataset: 3. Which of the following represents the last four digits of your primary checking account number?
This question is not stored in the dataset: 3. Which of the following represents the last four digits of your primary checking account number?
This question is not stored in the dataset: 3. Which of the following represents the last four digits of your primary checking account number?
This question is not stored in the dataset: 3. Which of the following represents the last four digits of your primary checking account number?
This question is not stored in the dataset: 3. Which of the following represents the last four digits of your primary checking account number?
This question is not stored in the dataset: 3. Which of the following represents the last four digits of your primary checking account number?
This question is not stored in the dataset: 3. Which of the following represents the last four digits of your primary checking account number?
```

## UPDATE: Page Object of page with 3 questions:

```
class LOA2KBAQuestions

  include PageObject
  include ErrorMessages
  include DataMagic

  h2(:question, :class => "question")

  #radio buttons for the answers for the first question
  radio_button(:first_q_first_radio, :id => "answers_question_0_1")
  radio_button(:first_q_second_radio, :id => "answers_question_0_2")
  radio_button(:first_q_third_radio, :id => "answers_question_0_3")
  radio_button(:first_q_fourth_radio, :id => "answers_question_0_4")
  radio_button(:first_q_fifth_radio, :id => "answers_question_0_5")

  #radio buttons for the answers for the second question
  radio_button(:second_q_first_radio, :id => "answers_question_1_1")
  radio_button(:second_q_second_radio, :id => "answers_question_1_2")
  radio_button(:second_q_third_radio, :id => "answers_question_1_3")
  radio_button(:second_q_fourth_radio, :id => "answers_question_1_4")
  radio_button(:second_q_fifth_radio, :id => "answers_question_1_5")

  #radio buttons for the answers for the third question
  radio_button(:third_q_first_radio, :id => "answers_question_2_1")
  radio_button(:third_q_second_radio, :id => "answers_question_2_2")
  radio_button(:third_q_third_radio, :id => "answers_question_2_3")
  radio_button(:third_q_fourth_radio, :id => "answers_question_2_4")
  radio_button(:third_q_fifth_radio, :id => "answers_question_2_5")

  button(:submit, :text => "Submit Answers")
end
```

Also I access the actual questions like this (they are all in h2 tags, I use regex to remove the # before the question. And I access the question by adding [x] after the h2 tag):

```
@browser.h2s[0].text.sub (/^\d.\s/), ''
```

So I end up not using the declared page object for the h2 tag, since I wasn't sure how to use it to access the 3 questions.

## UPDATE - Sample HTML of 3 questions page:

```
  <div class="question">

    <h2>


        1.
        Which of the following is a current or previou…

    </h2>
    <div class="answers">
        <p>
            <label>
                <input id="answers_question_0_1" type="radio" value="1" name="answers[question_0]" checked="checked"></input>


                RITEWAY

            </label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>
                <input id="answers_question_0_2" type="radio" value="2" name="answers[question_0]"></input>


                NEW ALTERNATIVES

            </label>
        </p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="question">

    <h2>


        2.
        I was born within a year or on the year of the…

    </h2>
    <div class="answers">
        <p>
            <label>
                <input id="answers_question_1_1" type="radio" value="1" name="answers[question_1]" checked="checked"></input>


                1936

            </label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>
                <input id="answers_question_1_2" type="radio" value="2" name="answers[question_1]"></input>


                1939

            </label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>
                <input id="answers_question_1_3" type="radio" value="3" name="answers[question_1]"></input>


                1942

            </label>
        </p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It might help if you could explain the logic your code is trying to implement. For example, it is unclear what the difference needs to be between the loop for the first, second and third question. Ultimately, I think you are looking for how to get specific values from a hash. For example, the `question` in the first loop is going to be a hash key - ie "question". If you want the actual question it should be `value['question']`.

Comment: There are 3 random questions generated in the application, I have a data yaml file (kba.yml) which houses these random potential questions and answers. So I have a loop for each question (hence 3 loops). Each loop compares the random generated question with my yaml file.

Comment: I see. Looping seems like a more complicated approach. Would it not be easier to get the question and then look up the specific answer in the YAML file? Either way, could you provide the page (ie HTML of the 3 questions)?

Comment: Yeah that's probably a better approach, any insight into that approach would be great! :) I'll update the question with the page object for the page with 3 questions. Thanks for your help Justin!

Comment: Can you provide the HTML as well? I am having a hard time seeing how checking the label currently works, as well as what it means for the third question to have 3 answers. Having the HTML will make it easier to see if the other approach is possible.

Comment: Updated with some example HTML of how the question/answers are structured. There is one random question generated that asks the user for their year of birth of within a year (thus having 3 possible answers).

Comment: I get the text of the potential answers from the labels and then compare them with the answers in the yaml file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70237/discussion-between-farooq-and-justin-ko).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with how the YAML file was being looped. For example, in:

```
KBA.each do |key, value|
  value.each do |question, answer|
  end
end
```

`value` is a hash, so the `question` and `answer` would not be the expected values. They will actually be key/value pairs. It should have been:

```
KBA.each do |key, value|
  question = value['question']
  answer = value['answer']
end
```

Instead of trying to interate through each question/answer the YAML file, I would look-up the specific question and answers. In the following page object, the `answer_questions` will:

1. Determine what the question is based on the h2 element.
2. Look at the YAML files to find all valid answers to the question.
3. Find and select the radio button that matches one of the valid answers.

Example page object:

```
class MyPage
  include PageObject

  divs(:question, :class => 'question')

  def answer_questions
    question_elements.each do |question|
      # Determine what the question is
      question_text = question.h2_element.text.sub(/^\d.\s/, '')

      # Get the valid answers for the question
      question_data = KBA.find { |_, value| value['question'] == question_text }
      unless question_data
        puts "Question not found: #{question_text}"
        next
      end
      valid_answers = question_data[1].select { |k, _| k =~ /answer/ }.values

      # Set the radio buttons if they match one of the answers
      answer = question.radio_button_elements.find do |radio|
        label = radio.parent.text
        valid_answers.include?(label)
      end
      unless answer
        puts "Unable to answer question: #{question_text}"
        next
      end
      answer.select
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Justin, does your solution take into account that the answers for all 3 questions could be the same answers: "NONE OF THE ABOVE/DOES NOT APPLY", and the dob/year question?

Comment: The `valid_answers` array is there to account for the dob/year question (or any question with multiple possible answers). The locating of the radio buttons is confined to the specific question div, so it should handle multiple questions with the same answer.

Comment: Cool, just a few more questions with the answer to better understand:

1) Can you briefly explain how the #Get the valid answers for the question part is working? I was unsure of the [1] part of the first line.

2) Where exactly is the radio button being selected (I don't see any 'select' method from PageObjects), I was unable to find that part in the radio buttons code?

Comment: Also can you explain how the end.select at the very end works?

Comment: Yes, the `select` at the end is for selecting the radio button. `question.radio_button_elements.find` returns a radio button element, which then has the `select` method called.

Comment: `KBA.find` will return an array that looks like `[1, {"question" => "the question", "answer" => "the answer"}]`. So the `[1]` is needed to get the hash in the second element.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70256/discussion-between-farooq-and-justin-ko).

Comment: Also how would I add a check to the code, so if the question is not in the yaml file, then it'll print to the terminal and I can add it later?

Comment: Re-factored the code to output questions that are not known or could not be answered. When the questions are found, the method will move on to the next question.